# Colors not working on TailwindCSS on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

I created a brand new project using Rails 6.2.1 and I added [tailwindcss-rails](https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails). Some of it works, but colors for example seem not to be working. The snippet from https://play.tailwindcss.com/ looks like this when I embed it on my project:

[image]

All my source code is here https://github.com/pupeno/imok

Any ideas what's going on here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to add the colors `cyan` and `light-blue` (used in the default [playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com) code) to `tailwind.config.js` since they [don't come with the default theme](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/master/stubs/defaultConfig.stub.js#L15-L29).

```js
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'light-blue': colors.lightBlue,
        cyan: colors.cyan,
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: I don't remember having to do this when I used TailwindCSS before and there's a default theme that provides colors (https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/master/stubs/defaultConfig.stub.js#L7), why aren't the colors from the default theme working?

Comment: @pupeno The colors `cyan` and `lightBlue` which are used in the [TailwindCSS playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/) [don't come with the default theme](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/master/stubs/defaultConfig.stub.js#L15-L29). Just updated my answer.